# iOS Next Button on Keyboard Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I have found this solution to making the next buttons on the ui keyboard go to the next text field, however it is not working at all for me. Is there something I have to do in the storyboard as well? Also, how do I make the next button for the final textfield call the unwind segue? Thank you

```
//
//  AddToDoItemViewController.m
//  ToDoList
//
//  Copyright (c) 2015 com.example. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *totalTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tipTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *singleTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *ccSwitch;

@end

@implementation AddToDoItemViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.textField) {
        [self.totalTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.totalTextField ) {
        [self.tipTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}

/*- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (theTextField == self.totalTextField) {
        [self.tipTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
 */


- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender = %@",sender);
    if (sender != self.saveButton)  return YES;
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber *totalOrder = [formatter1 numberFromString:self.totalTextField.text];
    NSNumber *tipOrder = [formatter1 numberFromString:self.tipTextField.text];
    double tot = totalOrder.doubleValue;
    double totalOrderWithTip = tipOrder.doubleValue;
    if(self.textField.text.length <= 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Field not entered"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;


    }
    if(self.totalTextField.text.length <= 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Field not entered"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;


    }
    if(self.tipTextField.text.length <= 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Field not entered"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;


    }
    if(totalOrder == nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Invalid Order Total"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;


    }
    if(tipOrder == nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Invalid Amount Recieved"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;


    }

    if(totalOrderWithTip < tot)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"The amount recieved must be       equal to or greater than the order total."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;

    }
    return YES;



}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {

        NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
       // NSNumber *tipPercent = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.0];
        NSNumber *totalOrder = [formatter1 numberFromString:self.totalTextField.text];
        NSNumber *tipOrder = [formatter1 numberFromString:self.tipTextField.text];
        NSNumber *actualTip = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:tipOrder.doubleValue - totalOrder.doubleValue];
        double tot = totalOrder.doubleValue;
        double tip1 = tipOrder.doubleValue - tot;
        self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.location = self.textField.text;
        NSNumber *percent1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:(tip1/tot)*100.0];
        if(self.ccSwitch.isOn)
            self.toDoItem.isCreditCard = YES;
        else
            self.toDoItem.isCreditCard = NO;

        self.toDoItem.total = totalOrder;
        self.toDoItem.tip = actualTip;
        self.toDoItem.percentage = percent1;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: Have you added UITextFieldDelegate in your class header?

Comment: Yes it is in the interface #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: Do I have to control drag each text field to the next one in the storyboard? Thats the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Have you set the `self.textField `'s delegate in the storyboard?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: In the Connections Inspector for the textField, drag from the "circle" under the section "Outlets" - "delegate", to the View Controller Icon. Or either you can set it in the `viewDidLoad` method. Some like: `self.textField.delegate = self;`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! But the last text field just makes the keyboard close, I want it to go to the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier method, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Connections Inspector for the textField, drag from the "circle" under the section "Outlets" - "delegate", to the View Controller Icon. Or either you can set it in the `viewDidLoad` method. Some like:

```
self.textField.delegate = self;
```

The last textField is closing the keyboard because your are telling the keyboard to resign its first responder condition. Just replace that line for the one that you want to call:

```
[self shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER" sender:your_sender];
```

And that's it!